# tree command: Can you prevent the formatting dependancy on the final item?

Tags: bash, diff, tree

I am using `tree` and `diff` to compare a local directory with a USB backup version of the same directory, and to identify noteworthy / discardable differences.

```
$ cd home/dir/
$ tree --charset=ascii -af . > ~/tree__local

$ cd {usb}/home/dir/
$ tree --charset=ascii -af . > ~/tree__usb

$ diff ~/tree__local ~/tree__usb > ~/diff-analysis.txt
```

But I've noticed that tree has the habit of leaving out parent branches for last items … Ugh, this is hard to describe with words:

```
$ tree --charset=ascii -af .
.
|-- ./bar
|   |-- ./bar/babushka
|   |-- ./bar/galeda
|   `-- ./bar/helga
`-- ./foo
    |-- ./foo/alpha
    |-- ./foo/beta
    `-- ./foo/gamma

8 directories, 0 files

# add a new final item.
$ touch zebra

# same command.
$ tree --charset=ascii -af .
.
|-- ./bar
|   |-- ./bar/babushka
|   |-- ./bar/galeda
|   `-- ./bar/helga
|-- ./foo
|   |-- ./foo/alpha
|   |-- ./foo/beta
|   `-- ./foo/gamma
`-- ./zebra

8 directories, 1 file
```

Notice how the files in foo/ have gained an additional pipe branch. The `diff` command marks these as differences even though the files themselves are actually not different at all.

This is *very* suboptimal for my purposes. Do you guys happen to know how to circumvent or prevent that? Can you force homogenous pipe branches all the way down? The `tree` manual makes no mention of formatting the "last" or "final" item.

Comment: You might want to compare `find .` in each, or use `rsync` as noted in one of the answers. You're trying to hammer in a screw.

Answer (score 4):

The output of `tree` is meant for display purposes and is less useful for parsing.

It would be better to compare the two directory hierarchies directly.  You may do this with, e.g., `rsync` like so:

```bsh
rsync --dry-run --archive --delete --itemize-changes home/dir/ "$usb_path"/home/dir/
```

(Including `--dry-run`, or the short variant of this option, `-n`, is *very important*.)

This command would tell you precisely the difference between the local directory and the directory on the USB device. Nothing would be changed on disk as we are running with the `--dry-run` option.  The `--itemize-changes` option makes `rsync` output a terse status string for each file or directory that it would have copied or deleted, encoding the reason for the synchronization.

Add `--omit-dir-times` to the end of the list of options to avoid listing directories whose timestamps are different.  Add `--ignore-existing` to make it ignore files that exist in both locations, even though their sizes or meta-data differs.  With these two extra option added to the command above, you would expect to see lines of output prefixed with

- `*deleting`, for things deleted from the local directory but not from the USB device,
- `cd+++++++++`, for directories added to the local directory, or
- `>f+++++++++`, for files added to the local directory.

Comment: This sounds like a smart approach … except, I get a lot of false positives: `cd+++++++++` entries show up for directories with identical file listings inside them in LOCAL and USB; and there's way too many of them. — Can the directory/file permissions be a factor here? I've got 644 for files, 755 for directories on LOCAL vs. 777 for all on USB (because I still didn't get around to try this user mapping file solution for this other issue that I have), https://askubuntu.com/a/74851/846446

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru You could try using `--no-perms` _after_ `--archive`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I see no difference. I've also tried `-rlgoD` instead of `--archive` w/o any effect. When comparing the dirs with `ls`, I sometimes see another time on the dir or a subdir, but not any of the files inside – or I see another link count. https://detailed.wordpress.com/2017/10/28/understanding-ls-command-output/ — I've had to read up on it – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34407685/link-count-and-ls-command –, not sure how a link count could affect rsync like that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get rid of the complete indentation and branch formatting in order to work better with `diff`:

> -i 
> Makes  tree not print the indentation lines, useful when used in conjunction with the -f option.  Also removes as much whitespace as possible when used with the -J or -x options.

```
$ tree --charset=ascii -afi .
.
./bar
./bar/babushka
./bar/galeda
./bar/helga
./foo
./foo/alpha
./foo/beta
./foo/gamma
./zebra

8 directories, 1 file
```

Too bad: the indentation helps me visually understand these things faster. But oh well …

Answer (score 0):

In each line turn everything before the first `.` into spaces:

```
tree --charset=ascii -af . | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {gsub(/./, " ", $1)} 1'
```